# Do we have a sys table which holds the copy of entire stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Do we have a sys table which holds the copy of entire stored procedure?

Something similar to syscomments which holds the entire sp in a column? If not available, how to save the entire sp in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the metadata table is called [sys.sql_modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns a row for each object that is an SQL language-defined module in SQL Server, including natively compiled scalar user-defined function. Objects of type P, RF, V, TR, FN, IF, TF, and R have an associated SQL module.
>
> Column **definition**
>
> **SQL text that defines this module.** This value can also be obtained using the OBJECT_DEFINITION built-in function.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db6426b70d1c473f3a0b38ff78f344e9)**

---

Another table is [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/routines-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0fd3558c28205002c591631d695554dd)**

Comment: @goofyui Unless it is encrypted :)

Comment: What if it is encrypted ? Just asking hypothetical scenario .. In our case, SP's are not encrypted

Comment: @goofyui Then you will get `NULL` value - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ac16d98b487e377678754089c4af5bdd